# Add property to React Typescript High Order Component including implementation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, high-order-component

I'm trying to build a React HOC that I want to do the following:

- Take a passed in component, add (or override) the `hidden` property, and return the modified component
- Render the component such that when 'hidden' is true, nothing is rendered

I have this working for specific components as follows in Typescript

```
import React from 'react';
import { FabProps, Fab } from '@material-ui/core';
import ButtonWithText, { ButtonWithTextProps } from '../UserInterface/ButtonWithText';

interface IFabWithHiddenProps {
    hidden?: boolean;
}

export class ButtonWithTextWithHidden extends React.Component<ButtonWithTextProps & IFabWithHiddenProps> {
    render(){
        const {
            hidden,
            ...buttonProps
        } = this.props;

        if (hidden === undefined || hidden) {
            return <></>;
        }
        else {
            return <ButtonWithText {...buttonProps} />;
        }
    }
}

export class FabWithHidden extends React.Component<FabProps & IFabWithHiddenProps> {
    render(){
        const {
            hidden,
            ...buttonProps
        } = this.props;

        if (hidden === undefined || hidden) {
            return <></>;
        }
        else {
            return <Fab {...buttonProps} />;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would like to turn these two classes into one HOC. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'd like the something that is generic enough to handle ALL component types going forward, not just these two cases so I can easily use the HOC on components other than `Fab` and `ButtonWithText`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you nee to merge your two interfaces and handle your problem like so :

```
interface IFabWithHiddenProps extends ButtonWithTextProps , FabProps  {
  hidden?:boolean;
  type : string; // this can be fab | button
}
```

and use it like so :

```
export default class FabOrButtonWithHidden extends React.Component<IFabWithHiddenProps> {
    render(){
        const {
            hidden,
            type
            ...rest
        } = this.props;

        if (hidden === undefined || hidden) {
            return <></>;
        } else if(type === "button") {
           return (
            <ButtonWithText {...rest} />
           )

        }
        else {
            return <Fab {...rest} />;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to abstract it further so that it works for all component types? I'd like something that works for all component types so I don't have to change every time I need to handle a new component.

Comment: just add more `types` or extends from more `prop type` to it and it will work fine as you want to

Comment: I would definitely like a more abstracted way of doing this, with templates, or maybe there is a better way.

Another issue is that when extending the multiple classes, some types that exist on one class but not in another, the `...rest` might create an error where a component does not have one property that is required by another (though I haven't tested that)